# My Suggested Edits intend to improve accuracy was considered as "does not make the post even a little bit easier to read"

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

I proposed a [Suggested Edits](https://ell.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/101691) recently and was rejected.

I guess it is important to use accurate term to ask questions, and "I love playing cricket" is *gerund* rather than *present participle*.

So, I don't understand why my modification is considered as "does not make the post even a little bit easier to read".

[image]

I am not asking a general question about the rules. I just want to know, why do some reviewers think less accurate term "present participle" **is better** than more accurate term "gerund".

Comment: Actually,  one user argued that the edit was superficial and not an improvement whereas the second user, who also rejected the edit, selected a **different** reason.

Comment: Related: https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5147/we-need-to-be-more-careful-with-suggested-edits-from-low-rep-users  I did my best to call on people to be careful and welcoming to suggested edits and new editors. Seems my idea is just unpopular and even hated by the old guard. What a friendly community.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have noticed you have been suggesting edits on a lot of old posts. I have rejected almost all of them. The posts were fine as they were, and also inactive. Had I approved the edits, the posts would have been bumped to the top of the question list.

I am concerned that as a learner you are getting close to the reputation needed where your edits will no longer be reviewed. You have the potential to do a lot of damage because, in my opinion, you don't yet know how to consistently make a good edit to other people's posts.

I can see you have a lot of energy, and that is good thing, as long as it is used on the right things.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Although it does not seems an answer directly to my question. Why do you think less accurate term "present participle" **is better** than more accurate term "gerund".

Comment: See also "easier to find". The answers all mention "gerund" and none mention "participle". A learner won't necessarily know the difference between a gerund and a present participle. Leaving the question as it is makes it easier to find for them.

Comment: I got it. I hadn't thought about that before, but now I have. I've learned a lot in our discussion. Thank you, that's very kind of you.