# Please look over the revision history when editing a question

Tags: discussion

So I just did a "reject and edit" for this question https://ell.stackexchange.com/posts/76087/revisions because the suggested edit was correcting an edit that probably should have been rolled back and the revision history was starting to look like a [game of Telephone](http://www.wikihow.com/Play-the-Telephone-Game).

An edit in the revision history by the original author was a much better starting point than rewording the edit that reworded the question, but several revisions had been made in the meantime and rolling back would have lost other good edits.

If you're going to clean up the tags or tweak the title, please take a quick look at the edits in the revision history. We all can make mistakes, and if our reputation is high enough that we can make edits without peer review, we don't have anyone double checking our work. I'm fairly sure that I may have made some edits myself that could have been better, so I'm not criticizing anyone's editing ability, just asking for the community to help each other by looking over previous edits when they're editing a question to make sure that it hasn't drifted too far from the author's original intent.

Examples of revision histories with problems. I'll keep updating them as I find them.

<strike>https://ell.stackexchange.com/posts/85983/revisions</strike> - deleted
<strike>https://ell.stackexchange.com/posts/88622/revisions - This one is awesome because there are multiple revisions dedicated to trying to decide what kind of formatting looks best for a list of three words - bullets? numbers? just blockquote? The tags and the title in the meantime are completely mangled.</strike>  - deleted
https://ell.stackexchange.com/posts/94014/revisions - this one the author rolled back.

Related (because I think attempting to correct the grammar is what sends many of these revisions off course): [When should I correct an ELL's grammar?](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2465/)