# Editing questions

Tags: discussion, editing

I am assuming that this site follows similar rules to other sites:

- if your edit is minor you can edit but do not try to edit too many posts or else it will pile up on the home page (unless all under the same question)
- if your edit is minor and the question was just recently posted, it should be fine.

Does this site follow this somewhat?

Comment: What does this mean? "The edits will pile up on the home page".

Comment: The importance of linking and citing your sources... @Lambie let's say you edit twenty "old" posts one after the other, what happens? They all get bumped to the homepage, regardless of how trivial the edit, even if it's just adding a period. Suddenly users see a whole queue of old posts hogging the main page.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Ok, I now  see what you mean. I would have called are pushed to the head of the question queue. Homepage for me sounds like a website. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: There are other issues with the quote which I find somewhat odd, two definite articles are missing (1) *(unless all under same question)*  and (2)  *and question was just recently posted*

Comment: Where does the quoted text come from? Is it from another SE site? Please cite & link (as @Mari-LouA suggested)!

Comment: I wrote it myself @MarcInManhattan

Comment: Oh, perhaps something like a bulleted list would be better than a block quote then? I thought you were quoting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. That is general Stack Exchange policy and there's no reason for us to deviate from that.

Comment: Thanks, I was just a bit hesistant as I felt I was editing too many posts (minor ones)

Comment: @DialFrost When I'm answering questions, I end up spending way more time editing than answering. For every question I answer, I probably do minor edits to 10, like formatting, touching up readability and removing chatter.

Comment: @gotube and Glorfindel please note the qualification in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

On this stack there is a general policy that we do **not** edit to correct grammar or spelling **in a question**, because those errors can give important clues to the English skills of the OP. Instead corrections may be offered in a comment or at the end of an answer. Corrections of format (failure to use block-quote markup, for example) do get corrected. I for one will revert grammar corrections of questions unless made by the OP.

Comment: I don't polish any question to error-free English. I do correct things where mistakes alter the meaning of the question to not reflect the OP's intent (like using passive where it should be active), or if it interferes with readability to the point where a potential answer-giver may just not bother, in other words, where the question as it stands is unanswerable.

Comment: Perhaps it's a good time to have (another) discussion about this? I found [this answer](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2467/18673) encouraging (most) grammar corrections, and [this one](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2770/18673) being more cautious. We're not just providing the answer for the OP, but also for future English learners. Books about learning English don't contain (deliberate) grammar mistakes, and we're primarily here to [build a library](/tour).

Comment: I'm fairly certain that this isn't an official policy, and I'm not even sure that it's "a general policy". It seems to be disputed (as @Glorfindel indicates).